# How to solve $\log_2 x = x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$y=\log_2x=x-1$$
I thought to write $$2^{(x-1)}=x$$
What should I do next?

Comment: Are you looking for a general technique, or this specific solution? By observation, it should be pretty clear that $x = 1,2$ works...

Comment: A general technique

Comment: the solutions are $x=1$ and $x=2$

Comment: @prishila Like Michael said, $x=1,2$ are the solutions. There are no other solutions.

Comment: In general the solutions to equations of the form $\log_b x = A x + B$ (or $\log_b x = p(x)$ for any polynomial $p$) are transcendental and have no closed-form solution. In this case we find by inspection the two solutions @MichaelBiro gives and prove that there are no others using some elementary calculus.

Comment: y = x is a line.  y = $2^{x-1}$ is a concave function.  So the intersection is at most two points.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Derivative Test**

Given $\log_{2}(x) = x-1\;,$ Here $x>0$

As you write here $2^{x-1}=x\Rightarrow 2^x=2x$

Now Here we have to find roots of $f(x) =0\;,$ Where $f(x)=2^x-2x$

Now $f'(x)=2^x\ln(2)-2$ and $f''(x)=2^x\cdot (\ln 2)^2>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

So $f''(x)=0$ has no real roots

So Using $\bf{LMVT}\;,$ We get $f'(x)=0$ has at most one real roots

and $f(x) = 0$ has at most $2$ real roots

So here we get $x=1$ and $x=2$ are the roots of $f(x)=0$

Comment: please don't use derivates. We haven't learnt them yet

Comment: Then prishila You can go for Mickep solution.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization)
$$
\forall x\not\in(1,2):\quad 2^{x-1}=(1+1)^{x-1}\geq 1+x-1=x
$$
with equality precicely when $x=1$ or $x=2$, and
$$
\forall x\in(1,2):\quad 2^{x-1}=(1+1)^{x-1}<1+x-1=x.
$$
Hence, the only (real) solutions are $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of equation in general requires a non-elementary function, the Lambert $W$ function. It is defined as the inverse of:

$$x=we^{w}$$

That is, given an $x$, find $w$. There are two branches when $-1<x<1/e$.

Now, starting with:
$$2^{x-1}= x$$

We substitute: $$\frac{1}{2}e^{x\ln 2} = x$$

or $$-\frac{\ln 2}{2}= (-x\ln 2)e^{-x\ln 2}$$

Applying $W$, we get:

$$-x\ln 2 = W\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\right)$$

Or:

$$x=\frac{-1}{\ln 2}W\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\right)$$

Since $0<\ln 2/2<1/e$, we get two different values.

That doesn't explain why the values are $1$ and $2$, of course.

It is generally true that one of the values of $W\left(-\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$ is $-\ln n$. This is equivalent to $1$ always being a solution to $n^{x-1}=x$.

The existence of another solution, when $n\neq e$, is because the graph of $n^{x-1}$ is greater than $x$ as $x\to +\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$. (When $n=e$, the curves are tangent at $x=1$.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\log_2(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and 
$$ \log_2(x)=x-1 $$
clearly holds for $x=1$ and $x=2$. By concavity, it cannot hold for any other $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.